# what would be the custom format code to display percents as if it were multiple by 1000  

Tags: microsoft-excel

or how can this be solved by having the input and output on the same row. custom format code solved this for numbers -- [Modify value of a cell using the old value as part of the new one?](https://superuser.com/questions/471751/modify-value-of-a-cell-using-the-old-value-as-part-of-the-new-one)

quotes:
"...you can use commas after the number format to display the number divided by multiples of 1000. For example, #,##0.000, displays a value divided by one thousand and #,##0.000000,, displays the number divided by one million."

but it doesnt seem to work for percents.

the input are percents, like 20%, which would be .20, the output is those percents in decimal form being multiple by 1000

couldnt find anything on http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx

Comment: Whats your input and output?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, just select custom format as `Percentage`

**OR**

On custom format, use this `0.00%`

```
A       B
20%     0.02%
```

Here B column's:

1. formula is `=A1/1000` and
2. custom format is `0.00%`

the 200 or the result it was suppose to be did not come up with this custom format

Comment: this custom format did display the result as if it were multipled by 1000